# How to reference a widgets that seems out of scope - adapted kivy/examples/demo/images

Tags: python, class, reference, kivy

I have edited the kivy/examples/demo/images files to try to do the following:
- for each added image, it also adds a button in a sidebar (different boxlayout)
- when clicking the button, it removes both the image and the button

In order to do this, I have created (this is short summary code to give you an idea)

```
boxlayout:
    floatlayout:
    #this is where the images, in their own class called "Picture" just like in the demo get added
    boxlayout:
    #this is where the buttons get added. I created a class for them called "PictureBtn"
```

When creating the Pictures I add a unique id to them. 
Then I create the PictureBtn and add the same id.
Then I populate the pictures and the buttons in their respective places. All is well so far.

Now the problem is that from either Pictures and PictureBtn instances I can reference the app, but I have no clue how to reference the other instance. The id's don't seem to be anywhere.

The way I understand it this is because they are outside of the scope. The id's only hold locally and since both PictureBtn and Pictures have their own root, I cannot get to them.

My full code is below:

```
    import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from glob import glob
from random import randint
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
# FIXME this shouldn't be necessary
from kivy.core.window import Window

#declare global var for keeping track of unique ids
number_of_pics=0


class Picture(Scatter):
    '''Picture is the class that will show the image with a white border and a
    shadow. They are nothing here because almost everything is inside the
    picture.kv. Check the rule named <Picture> inside the file, and you'll see
    how the Picture() is really constructed and used.

    The source property will be the filename to show.
    '''

    source = StringProperty(None)


class PictureBtn(BoxLayout):
    pass

class PicturesApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global number_of_pics

        # the root is created in pictures.kv
        root = self.root

        # get any files into images directory
        curdir = dirname(__file__)
        for filename in glob(join(curdir, 'images', '*')):
            try:
                # load the image
                picture = Picture(source=filename, rotation=randint(-30,30))
                picture.id='pic'+str(number_of_pics)

                button = PictureBtn()
                button.id = 'pic'+str(number_of_pics)
                button.ids.lbl.text= button.id

                # add to the main field
                self.root.ids.picspace.add_widget(picture)
                self.root.ids.sidebar.add_widget(button)

                number_of_pics+=1                
            except Exception as e:
                Logger.exception('Pictures: Unable to load <%s>' % filename)

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def RemovePicture(self,byid):
        #my attempt (obviously failing) at removing the Picture instance and the
        #PictureBtn instance with the id "byid"
        self.root.ids.sidebar.remove_widget(self.root.ids.sidebar.ids.byid)
        self.root.ids.picspace.remove_widget(self.root.ids.picspace.ids.byid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PicturesApp().run()
```

Then my kv file contains the following:

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    FloatLayout:
        id: picspace
        size_hint: 0.8,1
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                source: 'data/images/background.jpg'
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            height: 44
            Image:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 24, 24
                source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png'
            Label:
                height: 24
                text_size: self.width, None
                color: (1, 1, 1, .8)
                text: 'Kivy %s - Pictures' % kivy.__version__
    BoxLayout:
        id: sidebar
        orientation: 'vertical'


<Picture>:
    # each time a picture is created, the image can delay the loading
    # as soon as the image is loaded, ensure that the center is changed
    # to the center of the screen.
    on_size: self.center = win.Window.center
    size: image.size
    size_hint: None, None

    Image:
        id: image
        source: root.source

        # create initial image to be 400 pixels width
        size: 400, 400 / self.image_ratio

        # add shadow background
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            BorderImage:
                source: 'shadow32.png'
                border: (36,36,36,36)
                size:(self.width+72, self.height+72)
                pos: (-36,-36)

<PictureBtn>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: ''
    Button:
        text: 'X'
        on_release: app.RemovePicture(self.parent.id)
```

(My original code is a similar situation, but I created the same problem in one of the kivy/examples to try to make it easier to address.)

Thanks

Comment: I had an issue with scope in Kivy yesterday as well and solved it. You can see my question and answer. It involved Screens, so it's not exactly like your situation, but it may still help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366920/changing-kivy-widget-attribute-from-another-widget

Answer (score 1):

`id`s are only valid in kv, and are relative to the root rule. They are not application-wide global identifiers to refer to your widgets. Here's a quick example why it is this way:

```
<MyWidget@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        id: mylabel
    Button:
        id: mybutton

BoxLayout:
    MyWidget:
        id: widget1
    MyWidget:
        id: widget2
```

In this example, which widget would the id `mylabel` refer to? The instance in `widget1` or the instance in `widget2`?

So you can either loop through the children to find and delete the widgets, or you can store a reference yourself in a dict. For example, create a `_pictures` dict on the `PicturesApp` class, then when adding the pictures:

```
# add to the main field
self._pictures[number_of_pics] = (picture, button)
self.root.ids.picspace.add_widget(picture)
self.root.ids.sidebar.add_widget(button)
```

And your removal code would become this:

```
def remove_picture(self, idee):
    picture, button = self._pictures.pop(idee)
    picture.parent.remove_widget(picture)
    button.parent.remove_widget(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to find a way, but I am sure pretty sure there must be a better way:

```
def RemovePicture(self,idee):
    for child in self.ids.picspace.children:
        if child.id==idee:
            self.ids.picspace.remove_widget(child)   
    for child in self.ids.sidebar.children:
        if child.id==idee:
            self.ids.sidebar.remove_widget(child)
```

So this seems to work. They don't show up in the list of ids, but they do show up in the list of children. I am still not sure why this is. And if anyone knows of the better/more appropriate way of doing this, please let me know.