# kivy: Global variable and ScreenManager

Tags: global-variables, screen, kivy

I'm using an input from a `First Screen`, store this input into a global variable `CHOSEN_INPUT`, then when I go to the `Second Screen`, this global variable is displayed there.

I've got the beginning but don't know where to go... Maybe with `ObjectProperty` but I don't know how to pass it from one class to another.

global_test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


#global variable
CHOSEN_INPUT = ''


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    obj_input = ObjectProperty()
    obj_label = ObjectProperty()
    obj_okay = ObjectProperty()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        global CHOSEN_INPUT
        print('RESULT :', self.obj_input.text)
        self.obj_label.text = "You wrote : " + self.obj_input.text
        CHOSEN_INPUT = self.obj_input.text



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class FromFirstScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        global CHOSEN_INPUT

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        lbl = Label(Text=CHOSEN_INPUT)
        self.add_widget(lbl) 


class Global_VariableApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='firstcreen'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='secondscreen')) 
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Global_VariableApp().run()
```

and :

global_variable.kv

```
<FirstScreen>:
    obj_input: input_box
    obj_label: label_box
    obj_okay: okay_btn
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: input_box
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            multiline: False
        Label:
            id: label_box
        Button:
            id: okay_btn
            text: "Okay"
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
        Button:
            text: "Go To Second Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'secondscreen' 

<SecondScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Input from First Screen :"
        FromFirstScreen:
        Button:
            text: "Go To First Screen"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'firstcreen'
```

Answer (score 2):

Found thanks to @mcastle's solution : [Changing Kivy widget attribute from another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366920/changing-kivy-widget-attribute-from-another-widget)

I've put inside the class `SecondScreen` an `update_text` function :

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):

    obj_input1_box = ObjectProperty()

    def update_text(self, label_text):
        #print('label_text :', label_text)
        self.obj_input1_box.text = label_text
```

and in the kv file, I've inserted a function: `root.manager.get_screen('secondscreen').update_text(root.obj_label.text)`
(and put an `id` for the label of text of `SecondScreen` which is updated) :

```
<FirstScreen>:
    ...
        Button:
            id: okay_btn
            text: "Okay"
            on_press: root.buttonClicked(); root.manager.get_screen('secondscreen').update_text(root.obj_label.text)    ...

<SecondScreen>:
    obj_input1_box: input1_box
    ...
        Label:
            id: input1_box
    ...
```